# Inserting dynamic item in predefined set

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<button class='button' data-next="games" data-parent="games1" data-storage="128" data-graphcard="2" data-processor="i3">Click here</button>
```

Js.

```
let hardware = ["storage", "graphcard", "processor"];
const allButtonsToStore = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

allButtonsToStore.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hardware.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(`${el.dataset.item}`);
    });
  });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to get each item from the array and use it to find that data in the html. 
`${el.dataset.*}` where ' * ' = items of the array. 
So: get value of dataset storage, graphcard and processor of the button. This would be `${el.dataset.storage}` , `${el.dataset.graphcard}` and `${el.dataset.processor}`. In order not to write all of the items of the array, I'm trying to get all items in array (`hardware.forEach((item)`) and put in `${el.dataset.item}`

but since `` .`${el.dataset.item}`. `` is encaptioned by "``" I'm not able to escape after "`${el.dataset.`", insert the actual `item` and and capture it again in order to send the line with `}`

I tried things like `${el.dataset."item"}` , `${el.dataset.[item]}` or `${el.dataset.(item)}` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost getting it correct: the syntactically correct bracket notation is `${el.dataset[item]}`—i.e. without the extra `.` between `dataset` and `[item]`. See proof-of-concept here:

```js
let hardware = ["storage", "graphcard", "processor"];
const allButtonsToStore = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

allButtonsToStore.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hardware.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(`${el.dataset[item]}`);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button class='button' data-next="games" data-parent="games1" data-storage="128" data-graphcard="2" data-processor="i3">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Indeed the dot notation needed to be fixed. Thanks! accepting answer in 8 min